# TableColumn set width equal header

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

After i added a `MenuButton` I can not I can not get correct size

The `tableView` after load looks like this

[image]

How can i set each column's width to equal inner content width of that column ? *OR* Right blank space should be distributed in a balanced way

I can not do them both

```
tableColumns[i].setMinWidth(tableColumns[i].minWidthProperty().get() + 50);//does not work

tableView.columnResizePolicyProperty().set(...)//not work too
```